# Get the object with more properties from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, properties

Assuming I have the following array in a JSON file:

```
[
    { id: 1 },
    { name: 'foo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'foo', nick: 'bar' },
    { id: 4, nick: 'next' },
    { nick: 'nextnext' }
]
```

How to get the object with more properties? In this example I should get the third item: `{ id: 3, name: 'foo', nick: 'bar' }`

If there is another object with 3 properties, I can get two results or the last found, it doesn't matter, my purpose is to know all properties an object can have.

Comment: You will have to loop over them and count the properties to find the one with the most properties

Comment: Any smarter way?

Comment: There might be a shorter notation, but it will always come down to this.

Comment: What if there is another object with 3 properties?

Comment: @Rajesh Just get two results or the last found, it doesn't matter. Yes, I mean a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cope with multiple results, you could use filter.

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { name: 'foo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'foo', nick: 'bar' },
    { id: 4, nick: 'next' },
    { nick: 'nextnext' },
    { id: 6, name: 'another 3', nick: '3'}
]

const mx = Math.max(...data.map(m => Object.keys(m).length));
const res = data.filter(f => Object.keys(f).length === mx)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Was about to post the exact same solution, that's the correct one for that question.

Comment: Number of iterations here will be 2N.

Comment: @Rajesh  Yes, I suppose it's shorter than yours in code, but yours is faster in execution.  Maybe depends on what the OP is after. I'm up-voting yours as I like the idea of using an array and popping the last, neat trick.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array and put values based on key length.

Since you want objects with most keys, you can get the last item.

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { name: 'foo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'foo', nick: 'bar' },
    { id: 4, nick: 'next' },
    { nick: 'nextnext' }
];

var res = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  const len = Object.keys(c).length;
  a[len] = a[len] || [];
  a[len].push(c);
  return a;
}, []).pop();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `Object.keys()` to return the object which has more length.

Try the following way:

```js
var data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { name: 'foo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'foo', nick: 'bar' },
    { id: 4, nick: 'next' },
    { nick: 'nextnext' }
]

var res = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  return Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(c).length ? a : c;
})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What if there are two objects with same number of properties?

Comment: Exactly, and OP wants them both returned.

Comment: @Mirakurun, that is not mentioned in the question, it has come in the comment later...

Comment: Sorry, I changed my comment (if you need I can change my answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
let biggestObj = {};

for(let el of array){
    if(Object.keys(el).length > Object.keys(biggestObj).length){
        biggestObj = el;
    }
}
```

This should do the job!